# Detecting toasts in Marshmallow

Tags: android, coded-ui-tests, android-testing, android-espresso, ui-testing

I'm writing some ui tests with espresso and I'm trying to assert toast messages. The problem I'm having is that my code works on Lollipop but fails on marshmallow and I can't understand why.

My code is basically opening a dialog, filling an email and clicking a button. This should bring up a toast and it does (I confirmed with visual inspection on the device) but my test fails to detect the toast.

For this purpose I created a custom matcher class for toasts:

```
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.test.espresso.Root;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

import static com.google.android.exoplayer.util.Assertions.checkArgument;
import static com.google.android.exoplayer.util.Assertions.checkNotNull;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;

public class ToastMatcher{

    public static Matcher<Root> withToastText(String toastText) {
        // use preconditions to fail fast when a test is creating an invalid matcher.
        checkArgument(!(toastText.equals(null)));
        return withToastText(equalTo(toastText));
    }

    public static Matcher<Root> withToastText(final Matcher<String> matcherText) {

        // use preconditions to fail fast when a test is creating an invalid matcher.
        checkNotNull(matcherText);
        return new TypeSafeMatcher<Root>() {

            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("is toast");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(Root root) {
                int type = root.getWindowLayoutParams().get().type;
                if ((type == WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST)) {
                    IBinder windowToken = root.getDecorView().getWindowToken();
                    IBinder appToken = root.getDecorView().getApplicationWindowToken();
                    if (windowToken == appToken) {
                        // windowToken == appToken means this window isn't contained by any other windows.
                        // if it was a window for an activity, it would have TYPE_BASE_APPLICATION.
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        };
    }
}
```

As for my test case

```
@Test
public void success() {
    String successMessage = mActivityRule.getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.info_recover_instructions);
    String ok = mActivityRule.getActivity().getResources().getString(android.R.string.ok);
    // Click forgot button
    onView(withId(R.id.lg_forgot)).perform(click());
    // Fill email
    onView(withClassName(endsWith("EditText"))).perform(typeText(USERNAME));
    // Click OK button
    onView(withText(ok))
            .check(matches(isEnabled()))
            .perform(click());
    // Assert Toast
    onView(withText(successMessage)).inRoot(ToastMatcher.withToastText(successMessage)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

As I previously said, this works just fine on Lollipop, but on Marshmallow it gives me the following error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException: Matcher 'is toast' did not match any of the following roots: [Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@a66b932, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@a66b932, has-window-focus=true, layout-params-type=2, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#20 ty=2 fl=#1820002 fmt=-3 wanim=0x103045c needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1026, height=483, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}, Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@8d64683, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@8d64683, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=2, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=#11 sim=#20 ty=2 fl=#1800002 fmt=-3 wanim=0x103045c needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1026, height=598, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}, Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@90a2000, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@90a2000, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#81810100 wanim=0x103045b needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1920, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=3}}]
```

Am I doing anything wrong or that should be done differently on android Marshmallow?

Comment: did you tried catch a toast by its text?

Comment: Yes. I tried with simply doing onView(withText(successMessage)).check(matches(isDisplayed())) but that didn't work either so I created the custom matcher and it works just fine on other android releases except MM

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. Not sure if it will work on Marshmallow:

```
onView(withText(R.string.toastText))    
    .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(mActivityRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
        .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this but it also doesn't detect the toast on marshmallow